# When you change Magento Theme, do old products get lost?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, products

I've had this question for a long time now and I couldn't risk changing the theme and losing every product I have right now.
So, do the products and the old data get lost when you change the theme ?

If not, do they automatically start showing up using the new theme?

Answer (score 8):

As products and their logic are seperated from your design/theme, changing the theme is no problem and you will keep everything.

You will probably have to look out for specific functions or ways your theme displayed information, but it will be all there.

Comment: It would be great if you could mark the question as "answered" then, so other people find it easier when searching for a similar or the same question.

Answer (score 2):

**product is different and theme is different thing**

if you swich theme then design will change. so effected part is Widget, and cms blocks .

If you have CMS pages Then you need to redesign your Custom CMS pages according to your theme.

If you have created custom widgets then you need to set Widget block refrence and change theme in WIdget.

for product if you have crated some attribute and called them as your need in theme then those values you need to add except these all things were fine if you change the theme.

Answer (score 1):

The products have no association with the theme, the product, and even its review are not related to the presentation of these products, so change the theme and have no fear, your products are safe :)

Answer (score 1):

In magento products and theme is totally different things.

When you change theme it will affect to the front end design and layouts of the magento website. It will not affect to products.

Answer (score 0):

In magento products and themes are different things. So by changing theme it will not affect to products. So you can change theme.

Answer (score 0):

Changing theme will not loose anything. Products, customers and other things are irrespective of design. You can also keep 2 themes and keep different designs for different categories or products. There is a reason that code and design folders are different